# hidden из html в javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Сперва скриншот, как это выглядит в HTML коде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот же кусок в виде HTML кода:

```
<div class="LeftSidebar__section hidden"><div class="SidebarList"><h2 class="SidebarList__title">Your app</h2><ul class="SidebarList__list" data-testid="rootlist"><li class="SidebarListItem"><div class="DropTarget SidebarListItem__drop-target"><div class="SidebarListItem__inner"><div class="SidebarListItem__link"><a class="SidebarListItemLink" draggable="false" href="spotify:app:genius" data-sidebar-list-item-uri="spotify:app:genius" data-ta-id="sidebar-list-item-link"><span class="SidebarListItem__label" dir="auto">Genius</span></a></div></div></div></li></ul></div></div>
```

Всё, что я тут сделал, на готовой странице - добавил к классу "hidden".
Скажите пожалуйста, как будет выглядеть код на js, что бы так же скрыть это?

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Скрыть что?

Comment: Тот кусок, к которому я добавил hidden в html коде странице. Нужно, что бы расширение на js делало это самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.
  querySelector('.LeftSidebar .LeftSidebar__scroll-section .LeftSidebar__section').
  classList.add('hidden');
```

Comment: Да, большое спасибо, работает как надо))